# Table rows with border bottom look different at 3rd and 4th row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

It seems Bootstrap 5 table row with border bottom looked different at 3rd and 4th row? Can someone help me with this?

[image]

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr style="font-size: 12px;">
        <th scope="col-auto" style="width: 25px; background-color: #f2f4f7;"><input type="checkbox" value=""></th>
        <th scope="col-auto" style="width: 450px; background-color: #f2f4f7;">Product Name &amp; Store</th>
        <th scope="col-auto" style="width: 200px; background-color: #f2f4f7;">SKU</th>
        <th scope="col-auto" style="width: 200px; background-color: #f2f4f7;">Master SKU</th>
        <th scope="col-auto" style="width: 225px; background-color: #f2f4f7;">Price</th>
        <th scope="col-auto" style="width: 200px; background-color: #f2f4f7;">Stock</th>
        <th scope="col-auto" style="background-color: #f2f4f7;">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
      <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="width: 25px;">
          <input type="checkbox" data-productid="1882" value="">
        </th>
        <td style="width: 400px">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3" style="font-size: 11px">
              <img style="width: 75px; height: 75px;" src="https://via.placeholder.com/75">
            </div>
            <div class="col-9" style="font-size: 11px">
              <span>Mamaway ANTIBAKTERI Anti Bocor Tahan Lama, Mengangkat Payudara , Bra Hamil &amp; Menyusui
                                    Responsive</span> <br>
              <span style="background-color: #6020ff; color: white; font-size: 10px; padding: 2px 10px; border-radius: 30px; margin-left: 4px;">
                                    Mamaway
                                </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 800px" colspan="4">
          <table class="table table-borderless">

            <tbody>
              <tr style="
        border-bottom: 1px dashed red;
        ">
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  098811P-S
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  098811P-S
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  Rp 700000
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  6
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr style="
        border-bottom: 1px dashed red;
        ">
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  098811P-M
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  098811P-M
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  Rp 700000
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  0
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr style="
        border-bottom: 1px dashed red;
        ">
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  098811P-L
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  098811P-L
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  Rp 700000
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  0
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr style="
        border-bottom: 1px dashed red;
        ">
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  098811P-XL
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  098811P-XL
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  Rp 700000
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  0
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr style="
        border-bottom: 1px dashed red;
        ">
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  098811P-2XL
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  098811P-2XL
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  Rp 700000
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  4
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr style="">
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  098811D-S
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  098811D-S
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  Rp 700000
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  1
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr style="">
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  098811D-M
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  098811D-M
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  Rp 700000
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  0
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr style="">
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  098811D-L
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  098811D-L
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  Rp 700000
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  0
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr style="">
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  098811D-XL
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  098811D-XL
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  Rp 700000
                </td>
                <td class="text-start" style="width: 150px; font-size: 11px">
                  0
                </td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" data-productid="1882" style="font-size: 12px; text-decoration: none;">Sync</a>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Please don't beg in comments.

Comment: The issue in your image doesn't appear for me in Chrome. It's either a zoom problem (try resetting with Ctrl-0), or it's a pixel rounding problem due to your screen's resolution.

Comment: Protips: 1) Tag your Bootstrap version to draw attention. Also tag CSS, HTML, etc. 2). Create a snippet demo next time using the editor. It's easy. 3) Don't use inline styles. Everyone hates that. It's difficult to interpret and any changes require many updates. Use custom classes and CSS. 4) Simplify your demo code. You don't need that many rows to show the problem.

Comment: 5) Use Bootstrap's `img-fluid` class on your images so they don't overflow their parents.